# FastScroll in Relative layout, not a list view

Tags: android

I wanted to implement fastScroll like the one that is supported by ListView, but in a Relative Layout which has a large number of views, aligned vertically below each other. There are several different type of views so I can't use a list view.

I'm able to modify the thumb drawable for the scrollbar, but unable to make it work as a fastscrollbar.

is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT implement list view on relative, linear or any other layout. You will run out of memory very fast.

You can have list view with different types of item views. It's called heterogenous list view.

Take a look here:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Implementing-a-Heterogenous-ListView

and here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4777306/1535436